# Which font style is this?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, mathcal

Does anyone know which font style the 'a' circled in yellow in the image below is (this is in math mode)? My guess is `euscript` with `mathcal`, but it seems that `mathcal` does not apply to lowercase letters, unless I am wrong about that.

[image]

Comment: `mathcal` is only upper case.

Comment: this is euler cursive.  the latex support is rudimentary, but the font is defined in the file `ueur.fd` (part of amsfonts), and it wouldn't be difficult to provide more functional support by adapting the definitions in `euscript.sty` (also part of `amsfonts`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems simply Euler Roman to me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\EulerRM{U}{eur}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\[\sum_m \EulerRM{a}_m u_m(y)\]

\end{document}
```

[image]